# Cálculo de Balance (Credit - Debit) resultando em NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

Sou novato e estou aprendendo o bootcamp da launchbase.
Ao fazer um JS que calcula crédito - debitos, está me dando NaN, apesar que o TypeOf está dizendo que é um número...

Podem ajudar com o que fiz de errado?

```js
const user = 
{
    name: "Mariana",
    transaction:[],
    balance: 0,
    credit: [50, 120],
    debit: [80, 30],
};

function sumCredit(credit)
{
    const sumCredit = sumNumbers(credit)

    return sumCredit
}

function sumDebit(debit)
{
    const sumDebit = sumNumbers(debit)

    return sumDebit
}

function sumBalance(credit, debit)
{

    return sumCredit - sumDebit
}

function sumNumbers(numbers)
{
        let sum = 0;
        for (let number of numbers)
        {
            sum = sum + number
        }
        return sum 
}

const balanceCredit = sumCredit(user.credit)
const balanceDebit = sumDebit(user.debit)
const balanceTotal = sumBalance(user.credit, user.debit)

console.log(balanceCredit.toFixed(2))
console.log(balanceDebit.toFixed(2))

console.log(balanceTotal)
```

Comment: `return sumCredit - sumDebit` é a subtração de funções, você não está invocando elas para subtrair os resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa manter o seu código simples, o conceito de criar funções serve exatamente para que você dividir o seu código em pequenos pedaços que possam ser utilizados de maneira genérica em várias partes do seu programa, por exemplo: A suas funções `sumCredit` e `sumDebit` fazem exatamente a mesma coisa, invocam um método para fazer a soma do valor passado e retorna tal valor, ou seja não fazem nada, então você pode por exemplo eliminar elas e chamar diretamente a função que executa a soma dos valores passados.

Para fazer a soma você pode usar o [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) que aplicado em um array irar executar a operação necessária de acordo com a função passada como parâmetro. Veja abaixo um exemplo do seu código como poderia ser minificado e ainda sim mais legível e simples.

```js
const user = 
{
    name: "Mariana",
    transaction:[],
    balance: 0,
    credit: [50, 120],
    debit: [80, 30],
};

function sum(values){
    return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

const balanceCredit = sum(user.credit);
const balanceDebit = sum(user.debit);
const balanceTotal = balanceCredit - balanceDebit;

console.log({balanceCredit});
console.log({balanceDebit});

console.log({balanceTotal});
```

O mesmo acontece com a função `sumBalance` que soma os valores e retorna a diferença entre eles, não tem necessidade pois uma vez que você já calculou a soma dos débitos e créditos, você pode diretamente fazer a diferença sem a necessidade de criar uma função para fazer esta operação por você.

Comment: Eu concordo que o código dessa forma fica mais elegante, mas pode ser o caso de que fique mais difícil de alterar caso tenha alguma mudança para frente, como a forma que os dados chegam, por exemplo.

Comment: Pelo enunciado este parece ser somente um exercício, por isso não me preocupei com tais problemas. Caso um dia ficasse mais complexo, acredito que o correto seria criar uma classe `User` com dentro os métodos necessários ao invés de um simples json.

Comment: Ambos estão correto! É um exercicio porém quero já ter 2 funções (Debito e Credito) onde, ao alterar a funçao de débito, já seja refletido na função de balance.
O Leo proporcionou uma resposta clara que soluciona o problema de NaN, e eu agradeço por isso! Vou aprender mais sobre a função reduce, que no momento do curso não me foi apresentado.

Answer (score -1):

Tem dois erros no seu código. Primeiro na função `sumBalance` você está subtraindo `sumCredit` e `sumDebit` quando você teria que subtrair as variáveis que você passou para função `credit` e `debit`.

```
function sumBalance(credit, debit) {
    return credit - debit
}
```

Segundo erro é quando você está chamando `sumBalance`. Você está passando as arrays que estão dentro do user ao invés de passar os agregados que você somou. O correto seria `sumBalance(sumCredit, sumDebit)`.

O que ajuda você achar os erros nesse tipo de código é testar cada componente individualmente. Eu de cara não achei os erros, eu testei cada uma das suas funções e vi que a sumBalance não estava retornando o que eu esperava. Depois de corrigir a sumBalance ainda não estava funcionando, mas como as funções estavam corretas eu fui ver se tinha algum erro na parte que chamava as funções.

Comment: Continua com erro! Eu fiz cada componente, como você menciona, porém continua com NaN ou então dá erro. Veja a parte que editei:
function sumBalance(sumCredit, sumDebit)
{
    const sumBalance = sumCredit - sumDebit

    return sumBalance
}

const balanceTotal = sumBalance(user.sumCredit, user.sumDebit)

Comment: Eu editei a resposta para ficar mais claro a mudança na sumBalance